# Qt Connection conversion fail

Tags: c++, qt

I try to connect a `QGraphicsObject` subclass and a `QGraphicsView` subclass (with the following line in the `QGraphicsObject` constructor)

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(paintImage(QPainter *, const QImage &)), this->scene()->views().front(), SLOT(paintImage(QPainter *, const QImage &)));
```

But I get the following error:

```
D:\Project\Scene\PointField.cpp:18: error : C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const: cannot convert 'QGraphicsView *' to 'const QObject *'
The point types are unrelated; conversion needs reinterpret_cast, C style cast or function style cast.
```

I see from the documentation that `QGraphicsView` inherits from `QObject`, and there is the `Q_OBJECT` macro in both subclass declaration... Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 6):

`QGraphicsView` is an incomplete type at the point where it is used in the `connect()` call.  The compiler doesn't know that it inherits from `QObject`, and this is why it reports

> cannot convert '`QGraphicsView *`' to '`const QObject *`'

The solution is to `#include <QGraphicsView>` in the implementation file, somewhere before the `connect()` call.

Comment: I personnaly think that Qt makes some feature that are quite obscure, and this is an example. It is unintuitive and the compile errors do not give useful clue. Another example is QThread.

Comment: ***compile errors do not give useful clue*** The compile error told me exactly what the problem was.

Comment: @Krapow "Another example is QThread." Sorry for barging in, but if you're confused, carefully examine the various [related answers of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1329652+QThread), where I strive for correctness. If you're still confused, ask away. I might be tempted to write a canonical "everything you wanted to know about threads and Qt" answer one day.

Comment: I second that. @KubaOber does provide excellent answers. I have learned from many of them..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by including my QGraphicsView sublass header at the top of the QGraphicsObject subclass header, then clean / execute qmake / rebuild.